# Find all possible solution in Z5 with linear system

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I have to explain all  possible solutions of the linear system in Z5:

$$
\begin{cases}
2x+y+3z+t & =3\\
2x+4z+2t & =0\\
2y+3z+t & =1
\end{cases}
$$

ok now I go with Gauss-Jordan method:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
    2 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

now with elementary operations on the lines
I try to reduce to scale :
L2= L2-L1 (L = line)

and we are :

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

now L3 = L3 + 2*L2

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

now we have a matrix scale reduced.

Rank of matrix is 3(we have 3 pivot: 2,4,3)
If i delete last column of "known terms" .. 
Rank of matrix is in any case 3.

So we should have 5 solutions

The new linear system is :

$$
\begin{cases}
2x+y+3z+t & =3\\
4y+z+t & =2\\
3t & =0
\end{cases}
$$

...

now I continue with the method of substitution :

$$
\begin{cases}
y&= 3x + 2z +3\\
z&= y+2\\
t & =0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
y&= 3x + 2y +4 +3\\
z&= y+2\\
t & =0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
4y&= 3x + 2\\
z&= y+2\\
t & =0
\end{cases}
$$
multiply by 4 first equation 
$$
\begin{cases}
y&= 2x+3\\
z&= y+2\\
t & =0
\end{cases}
$$

I brig the "x" to the left in first equation :

$$
\begin{cases}
2x &= y+2\\
z&= y+2\\
t & =0
\end{cases}
$$

multiply by 3 first equation :

$$
\begin{cases}
x &= 3y+1\\
z&= y+2\\
t & =0
\end{cases}
$$

and afterwards I don't know how to continue for explain the solutions..

help me, how can I continue for explain solution?!

Comment: Now you've done. There are infinitely many solutions, described by the last system of equation you've got.

Comment: @user202729 Or, rather, there are $5$ solutions as we are in $\mathbb Z_5$... Substitute $y=0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: But ... when rank(Q)  Q = all matrix and rank(P) P=matrix without know terms,  is equal.. Don't have a finite set of solutions??
In specific 5 (because in z5) elevated to (number of unknows variable  - rank) ?!?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the "Z5" part, didn't realize that it is $\mathbb Z_5$...

Comment: ok @user202729 thx..

I had almost reached the solution and I did not notice it.
Drug moment

Comment: @user8734617 yes, thx :)